# /private/tmp is supposed to be writable, but still access denied

Tags: file-permissions, osx-el-capitan

I just can't write to my Mac's `/private/tmp` for some reason. I can't for the life of me figure out why, and the whole "fix permissions" deal from Disk Utility has been removed.

```
ekevoo@Anas:/private/tmp$ ls -la .
total 0
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root    staff  170 Feb 23 00:13 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root    wheel  204 Jan 28 00:23 ..
drwx------  3 ekevoo  wheel  102 Feb 23 00:13 com.apple.launchd.V3jYxoUD4k
drwx------  3 ekevoo  wheel  102 Feb 23 00:13 com.apple.launchd.lggbpq8CwQ
drwx------  2 root    staff   68 Feb 23 00:13 cvcd

ekevoo@Anas:/private/tmp$ touch aoeuaoeuaoeu
touch: aoeuaoeuaoeu: Permission denied

ekevoo@Anas:/private/tmp$ xattr .
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot
```

How can I discover the cause of this error?